# Prove that group $G$ has subgroup with index 2

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\langle x,y\mid x^2=y^2\rangle$, prove that exists subgroup of $G$ with index $2$.

Comment: @Mariano: It says so.

Comment: yes, this is my homework and i have no idea to prove that

Comment: What does $G=<x,y|x^2=y^2>$ mean ?

Comment: Perhaps $G=<x,y|x^2=y^2>$ means the group generated by $x,y$ with the single relation $x^2=y^2$.

Comment: This group is also solvable, interesting, and also torsion free

Answer (score 6):

The relation $x^2=y^2$ is the same as $xxy^{-1}y^{-1}=1.$ If a group $G$ has a presentation in which all relations have even length, then there is a well defined length mod 2 of any $w \in G$, since the process of reducing a word by cancelling $tt^{-1}$ does not change the length of $w$ mod 2, and use of the relations does not change the length mod 2 either, since the relations have even length. So there is a homomorphism $f:G \to Z_2$ taking $w \in G$ to its length mod 2. The kernel $K$ of $f$ is then a subgroup of index 2.

Comment: Elegant. Or at least my kind of argument. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $x^2=y^2$ is a central element of $G$ (i.e. it belongs to the center of $G$). If we quotient out we have $G/\langle x^2 \rangle = \langle a,b\ |\ a^2=b^2=1 \rangle$ (here $a = x \langle x^2 \rangle$ and $b= y \langle x^2 \rangle$). Now this is the infinite Dihedral group, and its subgroup $\langle ab \rangle$ has index $2$. Indeed $b^{-1} (ab) b = ba = (ab)^{-1} \neq ab$, so $\langle ab \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle = \{1\}$, $\langle ab \rangle \unlhd G$ and $G/ \langle ab \rangle = \langle ab \rangle \langle b \rangle / \langle ab \rangle \cong \langle b \rangle / \langle ab \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle \cong \langle b \rangle \cong C_2$.

Therefore $\langle xy,x^2 \rangle$ has index $2$ in $G$.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the abelianisation of your group. It is the Klein $4$-group. This maps onto the cyclic group of order two. Thus, your group maps onto the cyclic group of order two. The kernel of this map has index two.

In general, a group $G$ has a subgroup of index two if and only if $G$ maps onto the cyclic group of order two (because subgroups of order two are always normal), and the easiest way to check this is to look at the abelianisation.

Comment: This is a good way to see things --- the abelianization. Especially when the latter can be seen easily, as in this example. +1

Comment: I like your way - it is general, and a nice way to look at things...but it is kinda overkill!